# How to prevent SQL injection from client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

Is there any way to prevent sql injection from the client side. .i.e using jquery or javascript

Comment: Did you google or were stackoverflow your first stop?

Comment: What if the user uses a userscript instead of your JavaScript? Prevent SQL injections on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the client side so there is no way.